# I need help in querying the collection in mongodb nodejs

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is the document format in my mongodb collection named "jobs" in which I need to list all documents matching my query.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60a79952e8728be1609f3651"
  },
  "title": "Full Stack Java Developer",
  "skills": [
    {
      "name": "Core Java"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spring"
    },
    {
      "name": "Java"
    }
  ],
  "graduationRequired": true,
  "jobLocations": [
    {
      "name": "Hyderabad"
    }
  ],
  "isAvailable": false,
}
```

I need to query the collection "jobs" with information mentioned below that I receive from client:

1. skills: ["Java", "Core Java", "HTML", "CSS"]
2. jobLocations: "Hyderabad"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find()`

```
db.collection.find({
  "skills.name": {
    $in: [ "Java", "Core Java", "HTML", "CSS" ]
  },
  "jobLocations.name": "Hyderabad"
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E1vpMKTsPNn)**